# acquiring lock on a object over a synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

what does it mean when we say synchronizing to an object lock over a piece of code in java.

i mean what if there i try to synchronize over an object of completely irrelevant class which has nothing to do with the members and variables used in the synchronized block.will the threads still execute this code separately?
i cant perform multithreading scenario on my system as it doesnt guarantee an ideal output, so please tell what  object am i supposed to use in `sychronized(object)` while synchronizing a block?

Comment: `object` serves as a way to **scope** the synchronisation. Anything synchronised with the same instance of `object` will share the monitor.

Comment: yeah rightly so. but if i use synchronized(xyx) where xyz is any random class object irrelevant to the current class then will there be no thread safe execution for synchronized code?

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to *protect* your shared data with a lock. This means encapsulating it within a class which accesses the data while a dedicated object's lock is being held.

You are not supposed to leave it to a 3rd party's good will to use your locks.

Comment: thats fine. but how will i decide which object should i lock on to? is it always "this" or some other object .

Comment: @jayendrabhatt no it is not always this.  You need to know what data you are protecting, and ensure that any access to that data is protected by the same lock.  Which object is used does not matter as much as knowing which object is the lock and staying consistent.

Comment: if i lock a piece of code with a random obj then what all things can be protected (i mean what scope of things) . i know i am not finding proper words to put up this question:). but please try to answer

Comment: public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            c1++;
        }
    }

    public void inc2() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            c2++;
        }
    }
}  in the above case two different objects are used to provide lock on different code segments. so does it mean any Object can be used to protect whatever piece of code regardless of its class.  find the code in this [link](http://example.com)

Comment: Aa far as synchronization is concerned, the objext is reduced to its address on the heap. You  don't lock an object, you just acquire the monitor at that address.